# PHP Form Validation not proceeding

Tags: php, sql, validation, wamp

I have the following validation on a form which works flawlessly on wamp and redirects to the correct page with the variables in the header. but when I deploy on the live website, once I click the button it reload the page with only the header visible.

```
require_once "config/dbconnect.php";
require_once "header.php";

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$courseid = $_GET['courseid'];

$error = false;


if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
$validated = true;
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
    $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);

    $address = trim($_POST['address']);
    $postcode = trim($_POST['postcode']);
    $phonenumber = trim($_POST['phonenumber']);

    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
            $error = true;
            $email_error = "<font color='red'>Please enter a valid email address</font>";
    }
    // else
    //  $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    //  $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
    //  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['email'])){
            $error = true;
            $emailinuse= "<font color='red'>Email address is already in use, choose another</font>";
        }
    if(empty($password1))
    {
            $error = true;
            $password1_error = "<font color='red'>Please enter a password</font>";
    }
    if(empty($password2))
    {
            $error = true;
            $password2_error = "<font color='red'>Please verify your password</font>";
    }
    if($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['password2']) {
        $error = true;
        $passworderror = "<font color='red'>Passwords do not match</font>";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$firstname))
    {
            $error = true;
            $firstname_error = "<font color='red'>First name cannot contain invalid characters</font>";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$lastname))
    {
            $error = true;
            $lastname_error = "<font color='red'>Last name cannot contain invalid characters</font>";
    }
    if(empty($address))
    {
            $error = true;
            $address_error = "<font color='red'>Please enter your address</font>";
    }
    if(empty($postcode))
    {
            $error = true;
            $postcode_error = "<font color='red'>Please enter your postcode</font>";
    }
if(empty($phonenumber))
{
    $error = true;
    $phoneno_error = "<font color='red'>Please enter your phonenumber</font>";
  }
if (!$error) {
  $bindValues = [
        ':email' => isset($_POST['email']) && trim($_POST['email']) != false ? $_POST['email'] : null,
        ':firstname' => isset($_POST['firstname']) && trim($_POST['firstname']) != false ? $_POST['firstname'] : null,
        ':lastname' => isset($_POST['lastname']) && trim($_POST['lastname']) != false ? $_POST['lastname'] : null,
        ':password' => password_hash(isset($_POST['password1']) && trim($_POST['password1']) != false ? $_POST['password1'] : '', PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
        ':address' => isset($_POST['address']) && trim($_POST['address']) != false ? $_POST['address'] : null,
        ':postcode' => isset($_POST['postcode']) && trim($_POST['postcode']) != false ? $_POST['postcode'] : null,
        ':phonenumber' => isset($_POST['phonenumber']) ? $_POST['phonenumber'] : null,
        ':usertype' => "Registered"
];
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (email, firstname, lastname, password, address, postcode, phonenumber, usertype) VALUES (:email, :firstname, :lastname, :password, :address, :postcode, :phonenumber, :usertype)');
$stmt->execute($bindValues);
$userid = $db->lastInsertId();
header( "Location: payment.php?courseid=$courseid&uid=$userid" );
}
}
```

Can't see any errors on either wamp or live site

Comment: "reload the page with only the header visible" what does it mean ?

Comment: It is abviously isset($_POST['register']) returns false. Check your $_POST['register'] and its html.

Comment: `<font>` "Obsolete
This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."

Comment: HTML is fine because it saves to DB on wamp and then goes to next page. I understand <font> is outdated but just used as quick placeholder